# Create a contract that can restrict the sale of the token in exchange

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, truffle-contract, wallet-contracts, decentralized-exchange

Possibility of  create a contract that can restrict the sale of the token in exchange.

Restrict by not selling all token only particular percentage of token. 
To make use of the major token in platform.

Ex : if x Token is hold by the Certain investor. Should Restrict the investor from selling full token in Exchange.

Only certain percentage should be sold in the Exchange.

Should force the rest Token holder to use the token in Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need depart from standard contracts such as openzeppelin. Consider this process:

1. Create the token. 100% of the tokens land on the developer's address.
2. Create the token sale contract and the app. They start with no tokens.
3. The developer sends a portion of the tokens to the sale contract, because they are supposed to be sold.
4. The developer sends the rest of the tokens to the application contract, because it is supposed to use them.

You can see steps 3 and 4 rely on the developer's signing key and a regular externally owned account. It's the same account that deploys the contracts.

Many variations are possible to address your specific needs. For example, a scripted migration process, or special receiving functions in the crowdsale or application contracts for accounting or other worthwhile purposes.

Hope it helps.